# ZK Add component to specific page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, zk

I want to add Tab and tabPanel to specific page xxx.zul!

```
parentTabs = (Tabs) new Path("//root/lay/tabs").getComponent();
```

where root is ID for Page , lay is ID for BorderLayout and tabs is ID for Tabs Tag.

Note : Id don't have window tag in target page!

thanks

Comment: I've been working with ZK for some time and never seen anything like this. I'd highly recommend reconsidering your approach to whatever you're trying to do: leverage the framework, don't hack it.

Comment: You don't need to have the window tag but did you considered an include in your zul?

Comment: @chillworld No i didn't consider it in my ZK Page.

Comment: need help with that? (mvc or mvvm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke you can add a zul page to an other zul page by doing this :

```
<?component name="details" macro-uri="../folder/myzul.zul" inline="true"?>
<window>
...
<details/>
...
</window>
```

the code to handle that part is in your MVVM of the main zul page.  So if you do in the details an `@bind(vm.list)` you will need to have an `getList` and `setList` in your viewmodel.

Mine trick is that I write interfaces for those specific pages (you can implement multiple interfaces so multiple components are possible that way).

By that I know I will not forget any getter or setter that I need and they will remember me also on what variables I need to declare.

The visibility you can do with :

```
<tab label="tab2" visible=@load(vm.tab2Visible)/>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: @sw engineer Your welcome. If you want to add 2 times the same zul, search the zk docs for it cause you will have to do a little more coding.

Comment: @joshi thx, I learned again something today, how to make a code tag :)  Thx for the edit.